# Remove all elements which occurs more than one time

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an array like [1,1,2,2,3,4]

I want to get [3,4] by using a function like function answer(data,n)

Comment: I want to get only [3,4]

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen agreed. Re-opened

Comment: @connexo go through array, count occurrence of each item with a map. It's linear. Go through map and get all with count of 1. Or go through array and check which elements have a count of 1 - same thing. Both should be linear. It's `O(n)` at the end.

Comment: @VLAZHow would you do the counting without iterating the mapped array repeatedly?

Comment: @connexo `for (x of arr) map.set(x, (map.get(x) ?? 0) + 1)` or `for (x of arr) obj[x] = (obj[x] ?? 0) + 1` for using an object. Map operations should be `O(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

I would `reduce()` down to a map with the elements as keys, and boolean values to indicate whether the element has been seen before. Then it's just a matter of filtering out the entries that are duplicates:

```js
const data = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4];

const result = [
  ...data.reduce((a, v) => a.set(v, a.has(v)), new Map())
].filter(([_, v]) => !v).map(([k]) => k);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: From that linked dupe: `arr.filter(x => arr.indexOf(x) === arr.lastIndexOf(x))`. I'd be curious tho if there is a method that's better O(n)-wise.

Comment: @connexo The one-liner is `O(n^2)`: the `.filter()` is `O(n)` and for each item visited it `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` which are both `O(n)` themselves. So, `n*2n` total which simplifies to `O(n^2)` after dropping the constant. That's just analysis of the operations' complexity. In reality, `arr.indexOf(x)` and `arr.lastIndexOf(x)` are guaranteed to *at most* visit `length+1` elements. Consider if `x` is first - then `indexOf` will find it immediately, `lastIndexOf` will traverse the whole array. And vice versa.

Comment: @VLAZ You're right. `O(n^2)` indeed for the `indexOf` approach.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen still too much for this problem.

Comment: Seems to boil down to code complexity vs runtime complexity. The one-liner only takes me 2 seconds to understand what it does; none of the other solutions suggested seems that easy to grab.

Comment: @connexo I'd rather write 3 lines of JsDoc than introduce an operation of unneeded quadratic complexity...

Comment: Consider adding those 3 lines to your snippet then :)